# Using the same UIWebView across different viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

**TL;DR: I need to implement a singleton UIWebVIew that's shared across multiple ViewControllers.** The question contains all of my approaches so far.

*appDelegate:*

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *singleWebView;
```

*firstViewController:*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
    NSLog(@"Removing webview from the first VC");

    [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.singleWebView = self.webView;

    self.webView = nil;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *URL = [request URL];

    if ([[URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"myapp://postsShow"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"postsShowSegue" sender:self];
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

*PostsShowViewController*

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.viewContainer addSubview: appDelegate.singleWebView];
}
```

In the first view controller, I load my single page app, which shows a list of posts first. Then, the user views one of the posts and he will be redirected to the second View Controller. I want to *reuse* the UIWebView that was used in the first ViewController in the second ViewController so I don't have to *reload* the webpage.

The problem is that, after `addSubview` the UIWebView doesn't seem to be loaded. I only see a `UIView` that I use as a container. It would be really helpful if you could give me some debugging points.

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the size of the containing view? What is its size?

Comment: @Shripada Edited with more logs

Comment: i fear that the webview will not work right if mistreated this way... did you tried to setNeedsDisplay? on the webview

Comment: You can have a WebViewController to manage the web view. And instantiate this controller, wherever you want the web view, access from the controller. Thats more cleaner approach.

Comment: @Shripada I would have the same problem.

Comment: @PeterLapisu Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the problem.. :(

Comment: Did you try setting the `UIWebView` on `prepareForSegue` instead of `viewDidLoad`? Or `viewWillAppear`? I'm afraid `viewDidLoad` might be called while the first View Controller is still visible.

Comment: @pgb let me try it and get back to you

Comment: @pgb I tried again and unfortunately I am still stuck. Would you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: I tested with allocating a new webView instead of reusing, and it worked fine. But I need to reuse the already-existing webView that loaded the page already.

Comment: @shripada: if I instantiate a controller again, don't I lose what I had inside the webview before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out. The retain count was always 2, even after I removed the `UIWebView` instance from the `FirstViewController`. I removed the `UIWebView` from the storyboard and created it programmatically when the `firstViewController` was loaded. I left everything else the same. Finally I could start reusing the `webView`.