# Use same UIWebview in 2 viewcontrollers as a subview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, copy

I need to use same UIWebview instance in the 2 viewcontrollers as a subview.
But when i add the webview to the second view controller, its removing from the first view controller.
Both the view controllers will be visible at the same time. And I need to retain the same webview in the 2 view controllers.

I have tried of Archiving and unarchiving option. but the loaded details in the webview was not displayed when doing in this way.
Please suggest for any options.

Answer (score 1):

You are just creating a new pointer to the same UIView object. Since UIViews do not respond to copy, you will need to actually allocate and init a new UIView and customize it to match the first one

A view can only be contained in a single parent view's hierarchy. When you add it to a new one, it is removed from the previous one.

So, You can't use same Web view in both View Controllers. You have to create another one. You can't add same instance multiple time.

You can achieve this by following pattern:

*Create a common class where you can create UIWebview and load your URL and then add it to your controller. So you don't need to write url for every UIWebView.*

Comment: dharmbir - onedoubt why not we used via  abstarct class

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, we can use by make a abstract class but we need to create new instance everytime.

Comment: My need is I dont want to load the url in all the webviews. So I am loading the url in one webview, and want to use the same webview in 2 view controllers. do we have any option for that?

Comment: see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341819/using-the-same-uiwebview-across-different-viewcontrollers

Comment: @Bharathi You can do one thing create a common class where you can create UIWebview and load your URL and then add it to your controller. So you don't need to write url for every UIWebView.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh - welcome and add your comment to answer also

Comment: @DharmbirSingh .Yes I can Do that. But again its a same like, When i adding in second viewcontroller, and its detaching from first view controller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik You  mean i need to add comment also ?

Comment: nono bro, add this line also in your answer `You can do one thing create a common class where you can create UIWebview and load your URL and then add it to your controller. So you don't need to write url for every UIWebView.`

Comment: @Bharathi Please create a common class where you can create a instance of UIWebview and then you can directly add to your viewcontroller like... [self.view addSubview:[WebViewClass getWebViewInstance]];

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you :)

Comment: i am loading these webviews in pageview controller. where 2 viewcontollers will be visible at the same time.